# Change background of drawable shape in the layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gradient, android-drawable

This is my drawable circular shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#FF63a34a"
        android:endColor="#FF477b36"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```

I want to create this layout using drawable circular shape with different colors.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using `recyclerview` to inflate these items then you can this reference.
You have to take `GradientDrawable` from your drawable and then mutate your drawable based on your condition & logic. You can create your color array as per your requirement.

```
class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.myImage)
        fun bind() {
            val colors = IntArray(2)
            colors[0] = getRandomColor()
            colors[1] = getRandomColor()
            val backgroundDRw = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context.resources, R.drawable.my_drwable, null) as GradientDrawable
            backgroundDRw.mutate()
            backgroundDRw.colors = colors
            imageView.background = backgroundDRw
        }

        private fun getRandomColor(): Int {
            val rnd = Random()
            return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(56), rnd.nextInt(256))
        }
    }
```

The general idea is to get `GradientDrawable` from your drawable then modify background, color, orientation and then apply to view.